# Writing a Python program that uses loops to implement various algorithms

Tags: python

I'm writng a python program for a class and I keep getting these syntax errors and can't figure them out. The objective is to implement the algorithm in Python so that it correctly sets the values of min1 and min2, which should hold the two smallest values in the list, though not necessarily in that order. The code is supposed to be based off of this pseudo:

```
min1 ← list0
min2 ← list1
for each item in list
   if item < min1
   then if min1 < min2
      then min2 ← item
      else min1 ← item
   else if item < min2
      then min2 ← item
output: min1, min2
```

Here's my python code that I'm receiving syntax errors:

```
list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] 
min1 = list[0]
min2 = list[1]
  for item in list :
    if item < min1 :
      if min1 < min2 :
        item = min2
    else :
      item = min1 
    else :
      if item < min2 :
        item = min2

    print(min1, min2)
    return(min1, min2)
```

This code is returning: min1 = 4, min2 = 5, which is wrong :). Would greatly appreciate any help and advice as I'm new to Python. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is with the spacing after first line

Comment: Firstly, the body of a for-loop must be indented. Secondly, assignment is `=`, not `==`

Comment: Since your edit, you have new indentation problems. Please ask about a specific problem and include the complete error message for the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Sorry, the edits that are up there are correct now. The body of the for-loop is indented and the assignment should be =

Answer (score 0):

The lines need to be properly indented *(note: the recommended amount of spaces per indent is 4)*:

```
list = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5] 
min1 = list[0]
min2 = list[1]
for item in list:
    if item < min1:
        if min1 < min2:
            item = min2
        else:
            item = min1 
    else:
        if item < min2:
            item = min2
    print(min1, min2)
    return(min1, min2)
```

---

BTW, it is not a good practice to name variables with names of built in types.

Better to change that, and maybe make the function return `item`, and here is a cleaner form of your code:

```
def func(lst):

    min1 = lst[0]
    min2 = lst[1]

    for item in lst:
        if item < min1 < min2:
            item = min2
            
        elif item < min1:
            item = min1
            
        elif item < min2:
            item = min2
            
        print(min1, min2)
        return(item)


lst = [4, 5, 1, 9, -2, 0, 3, -5]
func(lst)
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: There's a more fundamental problem here that the OP has made, which this answer does nothing to correct, which is that he has misinterpreted the pseudocode. The aim is not to assign to `item` (why would you assign to the loop variable?) but to update the values of `min1` and `min2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to item everywhere. I take it you really want to assign to min1 and min2? You don't change them after initialization. That's why they are still 4 and 5.